# How to add a branch, created on a forked repo, to the upstream repo?

Tags: git, github, version-control, mercurial, git-branch

I was migrating my hotfix branch from Mercurial to Git. I used the hg-git plugin to import my hotfix branch into a new branch on my forked repo of my git project. Is there a way to add the newly created branch to the upstream repo? The branch does not currently exist on the upstream repo.

I tried to run...

```
git push u git@git.<name of upstream repo>.git hotfix
```

but got the error....

```
error: src refspec git@git.<name of upstream repo> does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'u'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `-u` instead of `u`. You can try this command: `git push -u origin hotfix`

**Note:** origin is the default short name for remote. You can use `git remote -v` to check if your remote short name is origin or else.